# bug with if statements and vuejs restart counter

Tags: javascript, if-statement, vue.js

I'm writing a simple piece of code that increases a counter every time you click a specific button and it restarts when you reach 3, the number is shown in each button, it seems to work ok however I have a weird bug: if the first button isn't set to 0 when you press any other button it restarts the first button back to 0. Does it seem the buttons are linked somehow?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    one: 0,
    two: 0,
    three: 0
  },
  methods: {
    chooseOne: function(x, y) {
      if ((x == 1) && (this.one < 3)) {
        this.one++;
      } else {
        this.one = 0
      }
      if (x == 2) {
        if ((x == 2) && (this.two < 3)) {
          this.two++;
        } else {
          this.two = 0
        }
      }
      if (x == 3) {
        if ((x == 3) && (this.three < 3)) {
          this.three++
        } else {
          this.three = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="chooseOne(1,one)">
      {{ one }}
     </button>
  <button @click="chooseOne(2,two)">
      {{ two }} 
     </button>
  <button @click="chooseOne(3,three)">
      {{ three }}
     </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have `if(x == 2)` followed by `if ((x == 2) && (this.two < 3)) {`? `x` cannot change in the time the next line is executed.

Comment: Your biggest problem is your code is not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If you make it DRY, your risk of inconsistency is `null`. Instead of repeating code only in View (which is what would happen if you didn't use Vue at all - if you used plain HTML), you repeat it in both View and Model. The goal is not to do it anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I'm checking my code again and there's definitely a lot of space for improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if-else is not consistent for all `x`. For 2 and 3, you have a nested check but not for 1. When `x = 2`,  this condition is false

```
if ((x == 1) && (this.one < 3))
```

So, `this.one = 0` is called whenever the second or third button is clicked

Add a similar check for 1

```
  if (x == 1) {
    if (this.one < 3) {
      this.one++;
    } else {
      this.one = 0
    }
  }
```

You can simplify your code to pass the name of the property like this to avoid multiple checks

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    one: 0,
    two: 0,
    three: 0
  },
  methods: {
    chooseOne: function(prop) {
      if (this[prop] < 3) {
        this[prop]++
      } else {
        this[prop] = 0
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="chooseOne('one')">
      {{ one }}
     </button>
  <button @click="chooseOne('two')">
      {{ two }} 
     </button>
  <button @click="chooseOne('three')">
      {{ three }}
     </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first conditional statement is wrong. Your condition is if (x == 1) else variable one reset to 0. When the second or third button is clicked, x !== 1, that's why the button's text reset while there is not any link between these button

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    one: 0,
    two: 0,
    three: 0
  },
  methods: {
    chooseOne: function(x, y) {
      if (x == 1) {
        if ((x == 1) && (this.one < 3)) {
          this.one++;
        } else {
          this.one = 0
        }
      }
      if (x == 2) {
        if ((x == 2) && (this.two < 3)) {
          this.two++;
        } else {
          this.two = 0
        }
      }
      if (x == 3) {
        if ((x == 3) && (this.three < 3)) {
          this.three++
        } else {
          this.three = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="chooseOne(1,one)">
      {{ one }}
     </button>
  <button @click="chooseOne(2,two)">
      {{ two }} 
     </button>
  <button @click="chooseOne(3,three)">
      {{ three }}
     </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be writing [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    one: 0,
    two: 0,
    three: 0,
    buttons: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  },
  methods: {
    chooseOne: function(y) {
      this[y] = this[y] < 3 ? this[y] + 1 : 0
    },
    getButton(button) {
      return this[button];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-for="button in buttons" @click="chooseOne(button)">
      {{ getButton(button) }}
  </button>
</div>
```

... which solves your problem because all your buttons run through the same routine, therefore the risk of inconsistency is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is your condition check. try this.

```
chooseOne(x, y) {
      if (x == 1) {
        this.one <3  ? this.one++ : this.one = 0
      } 
      if (x == 2) {
      this.two <3  ? this.two++ : this.two = 0
      }
      if (x == 3) {
       this.three < 3 ? this.three++ : this.three = 0
      }
    }
```